# PHP: System Timezone Setting error

Tags: command-line, timezone, php

I'm trying to use PHP in the terminal under MAMP but I got an error related to the system's timezone settings. How can I fix this error?

> $/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/php
>   echo.php
>
> PHP Strict Standards:  PHP Startup: It
>   is not safe to rely on the system's
>   timezone settings. Please use the
>   date.timezone setting, the TZ
>   environment variable or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function.
>   In case you used any of those methods
>   and you are still getting this
>   warning, you most likely misspelled
>   the timezone identifier. We selected
>   'Asia/Manila' for 'PHT/8.0/no DST'
>   instead in Unknown on line 0

Comment: The error message tells you how to resolve it - set the date.timezone setting, the TZ environment variable or use the date_default_timezone_set() function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set [date.timezone in the php.ini file<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone)

```
// London, England, Europe
date.timezone = "Europe/London"
date.default_latitude = 51.500181
date.default_longitude = -0.12619
```

or

```
 date.timezone = America/Los_Angeles
```

Comment: or the TZ environment variable or the date_default_timezone_set() function

Comment: Right. But for places where setting environment variables isn't easy and/or desired, setting the value in php.ini is better. And there should be a default value in there anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I followed this tutorial and the error disappeared. http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/getting-command-line-access-php-and-mysql-running-mamp-osx

Answer (score 3):

Set the default time zone manually at the beginning of your code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
```