# PHP get user's timezone

Tags: php, timezone

After changing servers I received the following error...

```
<b>Warning</b>:  date() [<a href='function.date'>function.date</a>]: It is not
safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the
date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you
used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most
likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for
'EST/-5.0/no DST' instead in <b>/sessions.php</b> on line <b>8001</b>
```

The line this error message refers to is...

```
$date = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
```

I'm not sure how that works though?

So how do I get the user's time zone and then set it either as a built-in PHP variable or use it with `date()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: System Timezone Setting error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533252/php-system-timezone-setting-error?rq=1) and [timezone problem - php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696833/timezone-problem-php?rq=1)

Comment: *sidenote:* `$date = $date = date()` ? re-declaration of `$date` ?

Comment: "if you see something unintuitive/stupid in any of my content then notice it;'s been edited by someone else" I don't think that's the case here.  Not sure why your [code] is improperly tagged for SO.  What is confusing about the error?

Comment: you can use PHP-GEOIP to get TimeZone of User.
Refer this link, hope it help http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.geoip.php

Answer (score 2):

As said from the warning, you should either:

1. set `date.timezone` in php.ini; or
2. set `date_default_timezone_set()` before calling `date()`

Answer (score 1):

Set the timezone in your php.ini file